# Along with Transclude element, can i pass its scope too to a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

Moment i felt i have understood enough about `Transclude` i came across this statement :

```
Transclude allows us to pass in an entire template, including its scope, to a directive. 
Doing so gives us the opportunity to pass in arbitrary content and arbitrary scope to a directive.
```

Does this mean, if there is a scope attached to Transclude element and it can be passed on to the directive ? If that's true then am not able to access that scope property inside directive template.

Let me take couple of steps back and explain with code about what am trying to do :

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/suman_jsfiddle/marssfa4/)

My directive is `directive-box` and `transclude: true` is defined in Directive Definition Object(DDO).

Now there is a Child Div, which is the element to be **Transcluded**

```
<div ng-controller='TransCtrl'>Inside Transclude Scope : {{name}}</div>
```

and it has controller `TransCtrl` attached to it.

Now am trying to access `$scope.name` property which is part of `TransCtrl` from directive level after defining this in DDO :

```
scope: {
        title: '@directiveTitle',
        name: '='
      }
```

Is this possible ?

This is more like a Parent scope trying to access Child scope property, is this permitted in JavaScript Protoypical inheritance ? Or is there something else i need to know ??

If this is not possible what does first statement mean ?

```
Transclude allows us to pass in an entire template, including its scope, to a directive.
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

My primary concern is Controller should remain with Transclude element, still we should be able to pass its (Transclude element) scope to Directive and then Directive should be able to consume that scope i.e., `name from TransCtrl controller` .

```
<div ng-controller='TransCtrl'>Inside Transclude Scope : {{name}}</div>
```

Above line of code should remain as is.

I may be completely wrong with my question but please let me if this can be accomplished.

Comment: If either answer was helpful please mark one as accepted. Otherwise clarify where more help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question: https://jsfiddle.net/marssfa4/4/?

In it I have created a new controller on the outside (effectively replacing the functionality of your rootScope for inside the directive) and I made the directive's controller be set inside your controller template.

The long and short of it is though that you can see that it is possible to transclude html along with its scope even into a directive with its own scope.

The html:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="OutsideScope">
  <h1>{{externalWorld}}</h1>
  <div directive-box directive-title='{{directiveWorld}}' name='name'>
    <div>Inside Transclude Scope : {{name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS (includes Update 1):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('directiveBox', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        title: '@directiveTitle',
        name: '='
      },
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div ng-controller="TransCtrl">\
        <h2 class="header">{{ title }}</h2>\
                <div class="dirContent">Directive Element</div>\
                <div>Outside Transclude Scope : {{name}}</div>\
                <div class="content" ng-transclude></div>\
            </div>'
    }
  })
  .controller('TransCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Transclude World'
  })
  .controller('OutsideScope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'External World'
  })
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.externalWorld = 'External World',
      $rootScope.directiveWorld = 'Here comes directive'
  });
```

**UPDATE 1: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/marssfa4/10/)**

I restored the original scope declarations as the `scope: false` was a mistake.

If I understand your comment correctly you want to leave the controller on the element to be transcluded but still have the `{{name}}` within that element ignore its immediate controller and use as controller its parent (i.e. the directive's) scope.

The reason I placed the controller within the template directive is because that is the only way to limit the directive's scope on the directive and not its transcluded elements. If you are explicitly placing a controller on an element, then regardless of whether it is contained within a directive with another scope, its closest scope will override whatever scope has been declared on the directive. In other words, regardless of what the directive's scope is, the `{{name}}` in

`<div ng-controller='TransCtrl'>Inside Transclude Scope : {{name}}</div>`

will always be whatever `$scope.name` is in `TransCtrl`.

Comment: thanks for your time. Plz check the UPDATE 1 in question. I have see you removing controller completely from Transclude element which is not what i want. Other thing you have declared 
`scope:false,
scope: {
    title: '@directiveTitle',
    name: '='
}`

I dont know if this is allowed or how does this work giving two contrary scope declarations in DDO ?

Comment: I updated the answer according to my understanding of your question. Basically you cannot have it both ways: You cannot explicitly set a controller on an element and expect it to be overwritten by its parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the way the controller is defined within the ng-transcluded html.

I have made it clearer by using

1. the bindToController construct
2. using a controller at the directive level

Refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/aditiraveesh/marssfa4/5/) fiddle for a working example.

```
controllerAs: "TransCtrl",
bindToController: true
```

And your statement, 'Parent scope trying to access Child scope property' is incorrect right? Since we are trying to use the parent scope property, i.e. name from within the child (ng-transcluded content), which is possible with protypical inheritance, and not the other way around.

Comment: thanks for your time but the alternate you provided has scope moved to Directive. Plz check UPDATE 1 in question.